# Execute portlet configuration changes after closing JSP in Liferay

Tags: jsp, configuration, liferay

I have already implemented a configuration window/JSP for a Liferay 6.1 portlet. 
The changes done in this configuration JSP are persisted in the portlet's preferences while running through the processAction method of the according ConfigurationAction and the configuration JSP is rendered again. 
How can I achieve it that the parent JSP becomes aware of the previously stored changes? 
In my case I have a (parent) JSP with a search form and a result list DIV below. 
When I open the configuration JSP (which opens in a popup window) and set a property to make the search form invisible this shall be done immediately after closing the configuration JSP (popup window) using the "X" button in the upper right corner. 
This means that if the search form was displayed initially and when then configuring the portlet to hide the search form the (parent) JSP needs to be reloaded and reading the preferences which should tell the JSP to hide the search form.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write an `AJAX` request with the url `<liferay:actionURL />`. Pass the value of your field as a parameter and send the `AJAX` request when you click the close button.

This will call the `processAction` but with `AJAX`, you will get the data from URL parameter, you can save that into the DB or session or preference.

At the success of the AJAX request, you can use `location.reload()`.

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event handler to execute some thing following an event.